# How to add crashanalytic in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

I am new in android, and I want to add crashanalytic in android application. After some research I found solution by fabric. but how to implement this I don't know with android studio or eclipse also. please help me. and If any other way to use crashanalytic in android.

please share me any link, by which I can implement this step by step.

Comment: did check their website. its well documented. Use android studio its the official ide for android development

Comment: install fabric in your android studio is will give you guidelines to add   crashanalytic in android application.

Comment: thanks @RakshitNawani for suggest me.

Comment: @RakshitNawani Any other way to implement Crashanalytic in android app.

Comment: Wait lemme search some more for that

Comment: thanks @Raghunandan for suggest me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]Go through this link it will give you detailed steps of how to install  crashanalytic in android application
[Fabric installation](https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/install)

Comment: thanks @Rakshit . it's usefull link.  can you guide me any other way for implement Crashanalytic in android app.

Comment: Do you have Fabric in your Android Studio ?

Comment: Go to  Default Settings open Plug ins and installs Fabric in your Android Studio and then follow instructions

Comment: can you suggest me . where is my plugin in default setting . I follow below path but I am not getting any plugin.. File->Other Setting ->Default Setting.. where is my plugin?

Comment: File->Settings. Then in Left hand side you can see the Plugins text click on it and I am attaching an Image in the answer for more clarification

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106314/discussion-between-rakshit-nawani-and-vaibhav-upadhyay).